# Google Cloud Build - Pass environment variable for Dockerfile

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I´m trying to dockerize my Angular application for Cloud Run and then conditionally build it with the production or the development configuration based on an environment variable.

*cloud build command*:

`gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/project-id/image-id --timeout=1200`

*Dockerfile*:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Copy local code to the container
COPY . .

# Build app
RUN if [ "$ENV" = "development" ] ; then npm run build-dev:ssr ; else npm run build-prod:ssr ; fi

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve:ssr"]
```

At the moment, the `$ENV` doesn´t exist, but is there a way to pass this with the `gcloud build submit` command?

Comment: Maybe this: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions

You will need to also add something like `--build-arg=ENV=$_MY_VARIABLE` to the arguments for the docker step. AFAIK, `docker build` does not pass environment variables, but build arguments have a similar effect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't pass build argument as you do with docker build command. To achieve this, you need to create a simple Cloud Build file

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/project-id/image-id', '--build-arg=ENV=$_MY_VARIABLE', '.' ]
  # push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/project-id/image-id']
images:
  - 'gcr.io/project-id/image-id'
timeout: 1200s
substitutions:
  _MY_VARIABLE: default value if not passed in the build command
```

And run it like this

```
gcloud builds submit --substitutions=_MY_VARIABLE=specific_value
```

Comment: Thank you for this clean approach.

Comment: Yes, it's normal, you need to add `ARG ENV` line in your dockerfile to say to docker to make the link between the outside world and the inside world!

Comment: Is this possible via just using the CLI?

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit

Comment: If you have multiple variables do you need to do a `--build-arg=ENV=...` for each one or can they all be passed into the same arg?

Comment: You have to use multiple build-arg

Answer (score 2):

Adding on Guillaume Blaquiere's answer

Do not forget to add the `ARG VAR_NAME` in the Dockerfile (it is like a placeholder waiting for the `--build-arg` input).
Adding only the `'--build-arg=ENV=$_MY_VARIABLE'` argument in the Cloud Build YAML file will not be enough for you to access the variable from the Dockerfile itself since you are giving an input to a placeholder that does not exist.